# C program works within GDB, crashes when run on its own

Tags: debugging, stack

This is a big project, actually a virtual machine of my custom design.

Under certain circumstances, program crashes with a segmentation fault every time when I run it on its own, but within GDB under those same circumstances it runs perfectly and never crashes!

I am giving it the exact same parameters and input when running inside and outside GDB.

So basically, I can't find the bug with GDB because it never has any problem when I use GDB.

The binary has been compiled with gcc -g option.

When I invoke

$ gdb ./main ./memdump

(where main is the complied program binary)

and give the bt command, I get "no stack". I read this means that the stack has been completely destroyed?

What could be causing this and how can I actually find the bug?

Edit: last few lines of instruction log

This output prints on screen, I redirected it to a file.

```
cmp    at address   313
je     at address   314
jmp    at address   316
inc    at address   306
div    at address   307
mult   at address   308
sub    at address   309
cmp    at address   310
ecall  at ad
```

It crashes at a random place each time, and usually fails to finish the printf() call, as you can see here. What does this mean?

I'm sorry, I actually had the wrong core dump file.

Now I have the right one...
Core backtrace shows:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040414e in int_call_internal_f (arg=14) at 
./opcode_func.c:1503
1503            if (memory[int_config[0] + memory[ip + 1]] != 
INTERRUPT_BLOCKING_VALUE)
(gdb)
```

This makes no sense because these are all globals and this line executes thousands of times after the values at those indices last change.

Comment: I suggest adding a logging feature to your VM where it outputs the state of its CPU every opcode to a file. Make sure you flush the output. That should at least narrow down exactly where the normal execution fails.

Comment: Regarding the partial printf output, this is probably a case of not flushing. You need to call `fflush` which will force the output out of your program before the next line. That way you'll get the whole line. (Also if you redirecting to a file it may buffer, consult your shell documentation)

Comment: Regarding your gdb: try printing the memory and int_config variable to see whether they are still pointing where they should. Usually I find this sort of things happens when memory is corrupted by writing past the end of an array or related.

Comment: But you can also checkout valgrind as @kdgregory suggested, it is designed to catch memory errors such as the ones you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, debugging C programs means that local variables (and other memory) are initialized to some well known pattern. When running in release mode, your memory will have whatever bits where there when allocated.

The other gotcha is optimizations. If you have a concurrency bug, running in the debugger will change the timing, obscuring things. Optimizations can also change the layout of things subtly so that pointer errors (offsets in particular) that blow up in release mode harmlessly overwrite unused bytes in debug mode (or vice versa).

Comment: Probably not applicable here. That is difference based on whether you have compiled for release mode or debug mode, not whether you are running the debugger or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gdb ./main ./memdump
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.

The second argument to GDB is interpreted as a core file, not the argument to the program.

You want:

```
$ gdb ./main
(gdb) set args ./memdump
(gdb) run
... wait for crash
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: That is actually what I intended, memdump is the name of the core file on my system. When I run the program inside gdb using set args to give the required arguments, it does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults are caused by the program accessing memory that's not within its legal address space. The proximal cause of the error often has little relation to the actual cause: the actual error might store an invalid pointer, which is then dereferenced from unrelated code.

One approach, as another person commented, is to add extensive logging. However, this most often shows you the proximal cause, not the actual cause: when the logging stops you have a fairly good idea of what the program was doing at that time.

A better solution is to use a memory checker, such as [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/). This tool instruments your code, and will catch and log illegal memory accesses before they turn into segmentation violations. It may also gets you closer to finding the actual cause rather than the proximal cause.

As a side note: most of the illegal memory accesses that I've seen have their root in pointer-based access to an on-stack array or struct.

Answer (score 0):

May be „no stack“ could mean not enough stack. Typically if large arrays/structures are not initialized on the heap (with malloc or new). You can check this in a gnu compiler environment with -fstack-usage which  creates a summary main.su file on compile.

Pointers not correctly setup or array boundaries crossed are also a reason, typically in debug they may point. somewhere or a write over a boundary may not crash the program but in a release version it does. Not sure how this is done with gdb but with Microsoft you can get this by CrtDebugHeap. May be gnu toolchain has similar options / libraries.