# C Program crashes when run, works in GDB

Tags: debugging, crash, mingw-w64

I am working on a program that crashes when it is run, but works just fine when debugged in GDB. I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090419/c-program-works-within-gdb-crashes-when-run-on-its-own) and removed optimizations and tried checking values of relevant local and global variables, with nothing seemingly out of place. It is not a concurrent program, so there shouldn't be issues with race conditions between threads. Windows Event Viewer logs the issue as a heap corruption (a problem with ntdll.dll), and I'm not sure what could be causing this. I am compiling with the 64-bit version of MinGW.

The program itself is rather large, and I'm not even sure which part to post. I don't really know how to proceed or what else I could check for. Any guidance if this is a known issue would be greatly appreciated, and if there is any other information I could post please let me know.

Comment: can you dump the memory when the process crashed? With that file on can look inside and see what was causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the issue - somewhere in the code, I was using `fscanf` to read in arrays of type `int`, but the variables that they were being stored in (i.e., the third arg to `fscanf`) were of type `char*`. Changed the argument to one of type `int*` and it fixed the issue.